# BigCommerce API Spec errors

Tags: bigcommerce

I am try to use the BigCommerce API Spec (below) in Postman but I keep getting the error "Error while importing: format not recognized" [Screenshot - Postman API Spec Import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sROD.png)

https://github.com/bigcommerce/api-specs/blob/master/reference/catalog.v3.yml

When I download the spec and import the file into Swagger editor online -https://editor.swagger.io/ - I get the below validation errors; am I doing something wrong here or how can I get this to load into Postman?

[Screenshot - Swagger Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk5jQ.png)

Structural error at info.contact.url
should match format "uri"
format: uri
Jump to line 85

Structural error at paths./catalog/products/{product_id}/options/{option_id}.put.responses.200.schema.properties.data.allOf.0.properties.option_values.items.allOf.0.properties.value_data.type
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: array, boolean, integer, number, object, string
Jump to line 4867

Structural error at paths./catalog/products/{product_id}/options/{option_id}/values.get.responses.200.schema.properties.data.items.allOf.0.properties.value_data.type
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: array, boolean, integer, number, object, string
Jump to line 5099

Structural error at paths./catalog/products/{product_id}/options/{option_id}/values.post.responses.200.schema.properties.data.allOf.0.properties.value_data.type
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: array, boolean, integer, number, object, string
Jump to line 5263

Structural error at paths./catalog/products/{product_id}/options/{option_id}/values/{value_id}.get.responses.200.schema.properties.data.allOf.0.properties.value_data.type
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: array, boolean, integer, number, object, string
Jump to line 5394

Structural error at paths./catalog/products/{product_id}/options/{option_id}/values/{value_id}.put.responses.200.schema.properties.data.allOf.0.properties.value_data.type
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: array, boolean, integer, number, object, string
Jump to line 5547

Semantic error at paths./catalog/products/{product_id}/modifiers/{modifier_id}/values/{value_id}.get.security.0
Security requirements must match a security definition
Jump to line 7941
Structural error at definitions.productModifierOptionValue_Base.properties.value_data.type
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: array, boolean, integer, number, object, string
Jump to line 18131

Semantic error at definitions.productModifierOptionValue_Base.properties.value_data.type
Schema "type" key must be a string
Jump to line 18131
Structural error at definitions.productOptionOptionValue_Base.properties.value_data.type
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: array, boolean, integer, number, object, string
Jump to line 19731

Semantic error at definitions.productOptionOptionValue_Base.properties.value_data.type
Schema "type" key must be a string
Jump to line 19731
Semantic error at security.0
Security requirements must match a security definition
Jump to line 21888

Please help.

Thanks,
Rory

Answer (score 0):

If the api-specs github repo, https://github.com/bigcommerce/api-specs, is not working when using with postman, you can use the Request Runners on the API Reference docs to do test calls.

This is a known issue. There are internal plans to resolve this, however, until then I'd recommend running tests in the request runner.